# Why do I have no trouble getting RavenDB UI admin privileges at home, but can't at work?

Tags: ravendb

I have seen some discussions about how to get admin privileges on the RavenDB web UI.  I actually had no trouble when I first tried.  I was at home.  I was prompted once for my username and password. I provided them and had no trouble.

Today I tried the same thing from the office and was completely unsuccessful.  I was prompted again and again, and was denied every time.   The main difference between being at home and at the office is that, at the office I'm on the domain.  At home it's can't see the domain or Active Directory or anything.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

RavenDB consider the following users to be admins:

- The user running the ravendb process
- Domain admin
- Local admin